# Walk on seven bridges with out walk on one twice (Koenigsberg)

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, visual

How i can walk on these 7 bridges without walk on one of them twice?

[image]

After some research i found that "Koengsberg bridge" is not an Euler circuit.

Comment: It's not possible...

Comment: @Ibrahim, if it isn't immediately obvious that the question we've marked this as a duplicate of is basically the same as this one, follow the "Seven Bridges of Koenigsberg" link in either the first comment under the question or GoodDeed's answer.

Comment: Since the question was "How i can walk on these 7 bridges without walk on one of them twice?", one of the solution is if you can swim(walk B-A-B-D-B-C-D, swim to A, walk A-C). Since you only said walk(not cross), you can walk B-A-B-D-B-C, walk halfway the C-A bridge, turn back in the middle, go back to C, walk C-D.

Answer (score 2):

> I say it's impossible to walk on these 7 bridges without walk on one of them twice.
> As the picture shows, each island has either 3 or 5 bridges connected to it, that's why I declare it impossible to walk on these 7 bridges without walk on one of them twice.
> [There's a proper proof out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg#Euler.27s_analysis) that shows that: To walk on bridges only once each, EACH island must have an EVEN number of bridges connected to it. Or exactly 2 have an odd number of bridges connected.
> Here, we have 4 islands having an odd number of bridges connected. So it's impossible to walk on these 7 bridges without walk on one of them twice.